# Kendo UI Grid ServerBound ClientTemplate alternative for conditional statement

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I have a serverBound grid that I am trying to do a conditional statement for the column. I understand that `.clientTemplate()` does not work with the datasource being directed by the Server, so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on alternatives to do a simple conditional statement.

**Example:**

```
 .ClientTemplate(
      "# if (tmpIsActive && Active == 1) { # " +
      "Sales" +
      " # } else if (tmpIsActive && Active == 2) { # " +
      "Corp" +
      "# } #")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of doing this.

### 1) Javascript Version

https://dojo.telerik.com/OWObuLOB This dojo shows you how to do it as a `template` all I have done is extract your simple logic and applied this in a template which is rendered using the kendo template engine.

```
  <script id="conditionalTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

    #if(data.OrderID %2){#
        I am an odd Number
      #}else{#
      I am an Even Number
      #}#



  </script>
```

this template is then called int he column set up like this:

```
 {
     field: "ShipCity", 
     title: "Conditional Field", 
     template: kendo.template($("#conditionalTemplate").html())
 }
```

## 2) Server Version (i.e. MVC Wrappers)

We can do the same trick here with using a template but in the `.ClientTemplate` string we put this in template:

```
 columns.Bound(c => c.SomeColumn)
        .Width(125)
        .ClientTemplate("#=kendo.template($('\\#conditionalTemplate').html())(data)#");
```

The alternate to this method is have the template being called from a javascript function which does this `templating` for you. Something like this:

```
.ClientTemplate("#=someTemplateFunction('{templateName}', data)#");

function someTemplateFunction(templateName, data){
      var template = kendo.template($('#'+ templateName).html()); 
      var result = template(data); 
      return result; 
}
```

Use whichever version seems the easiest for you to understand.

It is probably worth looking at the templating documentation to help you better understand what you can and can't do here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Any questions let me know and I will improve the answer for you.